# Angular (ionic) ngCookies can't read cookies

Tags: angularjs, django, cookies, ionic-framework

I using AngularJS + Ionic + Django.

**This is response of my request:**

[Response-Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blyC8.png)

[Response-Cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM4H7.png)

**This is my how i make request:**

```
    $http.get(ApiEndpoint.url + 'user/').then(function() {
        console.log($cookies.getAll());
        console.log($document.cookie);
    });
```

**This is console output:**

Object {}

undefined

How i can fix? Thanks!